# Someone ran 'pod update' and now my app crashes with podfile.lock issue

Tags: xcode8, cocoapods-1.2

We have gone through all the steps a million times:

```
$ sudo gem install cocoapods
$ rm -rf Bizzy\ Books.xcworkspace
$ pod install
```

Deleting derived data... changing build settings...

NOTHING is working! And all because one guy ran "pod update" and then didn't know what to do after that!

This is the error code:

> PhaseScriptExecution [CP]\ Check\ Pods\ Manifest.lock
>   /Users/Owner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Bizzy_Books-ajpeiroanshownarpormfcnuuvik/Build/Intermediates/Bizzy\
>   Books.build/Debug-iphoneos/Bizzy\
>   Books.build/Script-76499205B9A6D7551C8D0832.sh
>       cd "/Users/Owner/Desktop/Bizzy Books"
>       /bin/sh -c \"/Users/Owner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Bizzy_Books-ajpeiroanshownarpormfcnuuvik/Build/Intermediates/Bizzy\
>   Books.build/Debug-iphoneos/Bizzy\
>   Books.build/Script-76499205B9A6D7551C8D0832.sh\"
>
> diff: /Podfile.lock: No such file or directory error: The sandbox is
>   not in sync with the Podfile.lock. Run 'pod install' or update your
>   CocoaPods installation.

I am looking for somebody that knows what they are doing on this!

Plus, people are blaming me for having "old code" which is only like a week or two since the last pod install in which I had no problems. And there are no errors shown with the code, only with the podfile.lock issue.

And people are downloading from Github and saying it works fine therefore I have no problem, which doesn't help me, because when I pull from Github, it makes no difference, showing the same error!

Here is the github repository:
https://github.com/caldwbr/Bizzy-Books-iOS

Answer (score 0):

Well I finally got it working.

I opened the folder for my app and deleted Bizzy Books.workspace, Podfile, Podfile.lock, and the Pods folder, and emptied the trashcan. (Fairly important, if you don't want to see a slew of red untracked files hanging around after you do 'git status')

Then I navigated inside terminal to this same folder and ran:

```
git fetch --all

git reset --hard origin/master
```

Then I tested, and it worked!

I had been doing "git fetch --all" followed by "git pull --hard origin master," but I needed to do "git fetch --all" followed by "git reset --hard origin/master" and MAKE SURE NOT to do any "pod install" or "pod update"! That is the command that is giving me grief!

So thankful this is fixed!!!

There must be some incompatibility with a newer version of on of the pods in my podfile that just isn't working, hence I have to go back to the older version of that pod (not of cocoapods itself I don't think). Or there may be an issue with podfile.lock being funky as when you run 'pod update' or 'pod install' it generates a new podfile.lock file.

Comment: I should also mention that I was getting errors of "Apple Mach-o linker" and "Linker command failed with exit code 1" and "_TWTRIdentifierForAdvertising", etc. but now we are all good!